# How Can I remove leaf eater insect from the lemon plant

Tags: identification, diseases

I have one lemon plant in my house. I have seen a small leaf eater insect on my plant (picture attached)

[image: soft bodied insect on a leaf]

How I remove this insect from my plant. Please give suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what the insect is but it looks like a soft bodied insect and should respond well to 10 ml of dish soap added to one liter of water and sprayed on the entire plant.  Repeat the applications at five to seven day intervals at least twice.

Success lies with getting good coverage of the tops and undersides of the leaves and stems.

In areas of the world with intense sun you may wish to rinse the plant off after five minutes to prevent a buildup of soap on the leaves.

Answer (score 0):

That is a giant swallowtail caterpillar! Kind of rare to see them in many places. Don't kill!  They love citrus plants and will not do well switching them to another type of plant. If you know someone who has citrus plants outdoors or live near some orange trees, lemon trees etc. you can move it to the new plant. If you put it on something else it will starve. I wish I could take her for you!  They turn into larger bird poop looking caterpillars and then form their chrysalis and in two weeks emerge as a giant beautiful butterfly that is an excellent pollinator